# SystemC driving X when verilog top driving something on inout port

Tags: verilog, systemc

When we drive systemC inout ports from verilog top, I feel SystemC is by default driving `X` for that particular written bit. How to drive SystemC inout port from verilog top?

Comment: When there are two conflicting drivers on the same net the resulting value is X. In a bi-directional net, such as an inout port, only one driver should be active at a time. All over drivers output should be `z`s. In SystemC a disabled 8-bit IO driver should be assigned to `"ZZZZZZZZ"`. What was the last assignment on your SystemC IO driver before enabling the driver on the Verilog side?

Comment: Hi Greg, ok I have not initialized any value to inout port from Verilog as well as systemC model. I have declared the port in model as "sc_inout<sc_uint<8> >  IO" . I am not assigning anything in SystemC model and trying to drive from Verilog top module  but I get X for those particular bits. Could you Please tell example. Thanks Nidhi

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your suggestion where I have a 8 bit IO output and assigned in one method as Z "IO.write('ZZZZZZZZ') " But instead of driving "Z" on IO pin it drives "5A" (X1X1X1X1X). I am not sure about the reason. Could you please confirm Thanks & Regards, Nidhi